# Input text inside a map function does not change react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I have problem with input text when I try to change it return to previous value was working fine out side map func. but inside it refuse to change it value. I think it re render itself on change text.
so how do I change text and save name

```
userdata.map((l, i) => (
                    <Input label='First Name' value={l.name}
                      onChangeText={setname} /> 
<Button title="Modify" onPress={() => 
                    modifyDetails(
                      name,
                      )
                    } />
))
```

Edit: Based on Mohammad code  I have done this

```
<Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.centeredView}>
            <View style={styles.modalView}>
              <TouchableHighlight
                  onPress={() => {
                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                  }}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.textStyleClose}>X</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                   <UserDataWithCallback/> // inputs called here
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
</Modal>
```

But now renders empty inputs. Any solution.

Comment: then where is your map function? and do you use class components or hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useCallback will solve your problem.\

```
const userDataWithCallback = React.useCallback((l, i) => {
   return (
      <> // maybe a key prop is needed too
         <Input
            label='First Name'
            value={l.name}
            onChangeText={setname} /> 

         <Button
            title="Modify"
            onPress={() => modifyDetails(name)} />
      </>
  )
}, [])

userdata.map((l, i) => (
   userDataWithCallback(l, i)
))
```

Comment: But it return empty input value, first, console log show l.name's value and then return undefined.

Comment: may i see your modifyDetails function or even your full code?

Comment: I just paste the code not the app https://snack.expo.io/@mgonekar/edit-input-data

Comment: I saw your code. and here is an example I made for you. maybe this can help you https://snack.expo.io/e72qk4yEz. And I think my answer is no more usefull for your case.